# How to configure prettier to stop unwrapping my intended wrapped lines?

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, prettier

I have the following code like this in Typescript:

```
await expect(
  users[0]
    .GreetingsRegistry
    .setMessage(testMessage)
  )
  .to
  .emit(GreetingsRegistry, 'MessageChanged')
  .withArgs(users[0].address, testMessage);
```

I'm using `prettier` to format my code but it's getting extremely annoying as it keeps unwrapping my lines especially in chained calls. I intentionally put them in new lines for readability. But it keeps reformatting to this:

```
await expect(users[0].GreetingsRegistry.setMessage(testMessage))
  .to.emit(GreetingsRegistry, "MessageChanged")
  .withArgs(users[0].address, testMessage)
```

What prettier has produced is simply rubbish because it's so much harder to read now! I tried adding eslint rules into `prettierrc` but it doesn't work too.

How can I configure prettier to wrap multi-lines properly?

Comment: You can’t do much to how prettier formats code. There is a reason why it states that it is `An opinionated code formatter`. Either you like their way of formatting the code with the limited options or it is the wrong formatted for you.

Comment: Your only real option if you intend to keep using prettier is to put `// prettier-ignore` right above that

Comment: Prettier gonna prettier, and that's the whole point. I sometimes add an empty comment to force prettier to make a new line there. But that works better for array literals and in this case it doesn't help much. But for what its worth, I kind of agree with prettier here. Your first snippet's lack of indentation makes it hard to see where the `expect()` actually ends, where in prettier version, it's clear it ends at the end of the first line.

Comment: @AlexWayne Thanks for mentioning that. I didn't notice about the indentation issue when I copied and pasted into my question. I've updated my question with my intended indentation.